# Compact <--> Regular size change via rotation = Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints when using auto-layout programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I have defined four buttons programmatically and added them to UIStackview name 'finalStack'.  During rotation I am able to successfully change finalStack orientation but I am unable to move it after adjusting centerY-anchor value.  From the console, I have errors stating that I am failing to remove the previous constraints.  Is my code to de-activate the constraints incorrect or am I missing something else? The two print statements in my if/else statement tell me that I am correctly hitting the appropriate code block after rotating device.

Simulator is using iPhone XR

In the meantime I'm trying to follow the recommendations and trying to implement symbolic breakpoints but that topic is turning into another major task for me.  Would greatly appreciate any insight into either topic.  [Console Warnings after device rotates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXNDj.png)

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    finalStack.addArrangedSubview(buttonOne)
    finalStack.addArrangedSubview(buttonTwo)
    finalStack.addArrangedSubview(buttonThree)
    finalStack.addArrangedSubview(buttonFour)
    view.addSubview(finalStack)
}


override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    let compactContraints = [
        finalStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        finalStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        buttonOne.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        buttonOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        buttonTwo.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        buttonTwo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        buttonThree.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        buttonThree.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        buttonFour.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        buttonFour.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        ]

    let regularConstraints = [
        finalStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        finalStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -100),
        buttonOne.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        buttonOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        buttonTwo.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        buttonTwo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        buttonThree.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        buttonThree.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        buttonFour.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        buttonFour.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        ]


    if traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact {
        finalStack.axis = .horizontal
        print("vertical class = compact")
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(regularConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(compactContraints)
    } else if traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .regular{
        finalStack.axis = .vertical
        print("vertical class = regular")
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(compactContraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(regularConstraints)
    }
}
```

}